# Load data from JSON file in assets with NUXT.js

Tags: json, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

Suppose I have `assets/data/geo/regions.json` file in my NUXT.js project folders structure. How can I read data from this file into my project?

I have tried **axios** but I don't know what URL will have this file, I have tried all possible URLs. What is the better solution to do that? Maybe better to hold JSON files in `static` folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the `regions.json` file won't change, you can easily put it in the `static` folder.
Then the url will be `/data/geo/regions.json`
See this question [on the nuxt issues page](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/123)

Comment: Moved my JSON files to the `static/` folder and loaded them with __axios__. The link from this answer is useful. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share your solution @Dmytro Zarezenko ? just try and get the error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'

Comment: @ÂngeloRigo you can try this: `import json from "~/static/json/sample.json";`.  By prepending `~/static`

Answer (score 8):

You can import JSON files with `import data from 'data.json'` and use the `data` property straight in your component.

Comment: Ok, but what if the filename is dynamic and I want to load few files in a loop?

Comment: this approach works nicely when you place your JSON in @/store

Comment: @DmytroZarezenko you will need to use dynamic imports for that

Comment: worked perfectly for storing something in the assets folder `import data from '~/assets/countries_states.json'`

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Nuxt Content](https://content.nuxtjs.org/) for that:

> Empower your NuxtJS application with @nuxt/content module: write in a content/ directory and fetch your Markdown, JSON, YAML, XML and CSV files through a MongoDB like API, acting as a Git-based Headless CMS.

The basics are as easy as the following line. That will load the regions.json file, parse it, and store its content in the `content` variable. See Nuxt Content's documentation for more information about it.

```
const content = await this.$content('regions').fetch()
```

Alternatively you can read our blog post about
[Using Nuxt Content with a JSON File](https://frontaid.io/blog/using-nuxt-content-with-json-file/). It describes how to extend existing pages with JSON content but also how to dynamically generate pages based on it.

<sub>Disclaimer: I work at FrontAid CMS.</sub>

Comment: I've tried nuxt content with the example given in the doc. It works with the example, however, if you change just the attributes name by something else then the example in the doc, you get nothing. So, when I read all this I kind of assumed that you could give any json with any attribute to Content and get the result in your component...but no.

Comment: Yes you can. You should ask a new question and add details.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to use "require" instead of "import" if you planning to load data within the loop.

```
jsons = ["json_one","json_two"]
jsons_readed = []

// In the loop
file = require(`./assets/data/geo/${jsons[i]}`)
jsons_readed.push(file)
```

Then I think you can use jsons_readed to access objects.